# Print chart from For loop using user input (w/o vector)

Tags: c++

The Athletics department needs a program that calculate the area of “n” basketball courts. You’re hired you to write a report of the total area covered by the all of them. (The sum of them) and report the largest basketball court amongst them. Your program should contain a function definition to write to a file and function definition computing the largest basket-ball court below apart from main function. 
The should perform below operations

- 1)         The program should ask value of “n” (number of courts)
- 2)         The program asks for full name of each court, then the width and length.
  (The name can be a composite name such as “St James Arena”),
- 3)         Calculate the n areas and the sum.  (you should loops and if statements to determine the biggest court and it name)
- 4)         Then output the following report and save it to a file in the HDD.

Example:

```
>BASKETBALL COURTS AREA REPORT
>Court Name             Length                 Width
>Bay Arena                  30                    28
>Michael Center             26                    23
>The total area covered by all of the them together is: 1438
>The largest basketball court is Bay Arena: 840
```

So I figured out how to get the user data and print it the way I want using setw(), but every time it goes through the for loop it breaks the chart. So it looks like:

```
Court name: (user input)
Length: (user input)
Width: (user input) /
(prints court name) (prints length) (prints width) 

Court name: (user input)
Length: (user input)
Width: (user input) /
(prints court name) (prints length) (prints width)
```

and it does it however many courts are necessary. I don't know how to just print all of them at the end to create the chart. I also don't know how to say the largest court's name and area.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main (){
    string court;
    int numberofCourts, length, width, area, total;

    cout << "Number of courts: ";
    cin >> numberofCourts;
    cin.ignore();

    for (int i=1; i<=numberofCourts; i++){

        cout << "Name: ";
        getline (cin, court);

        cout << "Length: ";
        cin >> length;

        cout << "Width: ";
        cin >> width;

        if (i<=numberofCourts){
            cout << setw(10)<< court;
            cout << setw(10)<< length;
            cout << setw(10)<< width << endl;
        }
        cin.ignore();
      area= length*width;
      total+=area;

    }

    cout << "The total area covered by all of the them together is: " << total << endl;
    cout << "The largest basketball court is " << endl;

}
```

I got a big part of it done, I just don't know how to piece it all together.

Comment: what is your problem ? yes you almost done all even you need to separate the work in several functions as required in the description and there are some possible remarks

Comment: I just don't know how to make it print into a chart. It'll print each loop cleanly, but the chart is broken once it asks for the user's next input.

Comment: I edited my answer to not use a vector nor any other collection, with a full proposal

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how to just print all of them at the end to create the chart. I also don't know how to say the largest court's name and area.

you cannot use a vector, supposing you cannot use/create any collection by yourself you need to write in the file each time you read a court description, also computing the current max area and sum, then at the end write the sum and max

A proposal using a dedicated class :

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct Court {
  string name;
  int length;
  int width;

  bool read();
  void write(std::ostream & os, size_t wname, size_t wlength, size_t wwidth) const;
  int area() const { return length * width; }
};

bool Court::read() {
  cin.ignore();

  cout << "Name: ";
  if (!getline(cin, name))
    return false;

  cout << "Length: ";
  if (!(cin >> length))
    return false;

  cout << "Width: ";
  if (!(cin >> width))
    return false;

  return true;
}

void Court::write(std::ostream & os, size_t wname, size_t wlength, size_t wwidth) const 
{
  os << name;
  if (name.length() < wname)
    os << setw(wname - name.length()) << ' ';

  os << setw(wlength) << length << setw(wwidth) << width << endl;
}

void stats(int & max, int & sum, int area)
{
  if (area > max)
    max = area;

  sum += area;
}

int main ()
{
  int numberofCourts;

  cout << "Number of courts: ";
  if (!(cin >> numberofCourts)) {
    cerr << "invalid numner of courts" << endl;
    return -1;
  }

  ofstream os("courts.txt");

  if (!os.is_open()) {
    cerr << "cannot open 'courts.txt'" << endl;
    return -1;
  }

  os << "BASKETBALL COURTS AREA REPORT" << endl
    << "Court Name             Length                 Width" << endl;

  int max = 0, sum = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i != numberofCourts; ++i) {
    Court court;

    if (!court.read()){
      cerr << "error reading a court" << endl;
      return -1;
    }

    court.write(os, 23, 6, 22);
    stats(max, sum, court.area());
  }

  os << "The total area covered by all of the them together is: " << sum << endl;
  os << "The largest basketball court is: " << max << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wextra -Wall court.cc 
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Number of courts: 2
Name: Bay Arena
Length: 30
Width: 28
Name: Michael Center
Length: 26
Width: 23
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat courts.txt 
BASKETBALL COURTS AREA REPORT
Court Name             Length                 Width
Bay Arena                  30                    28
Michael Center             26                    23
The total area covered by all of the them together is: 1438
The largest basketball court is: 840
```

Comment: The question explicitely states _without_ `std::vector` (as silly that requirement may be).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ oh, didn't noticed .. or I forgot, thank you